Chain Breaks When Animated
I'm a beginner in animation. I have searched for videos, and it's now the fourth day I struggle with this problem.
I just need to attach a little chain to a pair of animated glasses so it moves with them. I have managed to attach the top ring of the chain and apply gravity to the other rings, but the chain keeps breaking.

These are the solutions I have tried:

Applying the scale
Setting the origin at the center of each individual ring
Trying different margin values

I think my geometry is pretty simple, and I can't see what the problem is.

File to see what's happening

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/20970/rigid-body-breaking-links-of-chain https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7280/reel-in-anchor-using-physics/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135896/rigid-body-problem-objects-not-colliding/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36235/why-do-my-chains-separate-when-falling-when-i-use-physics-with-them https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/238085/hanging-chain-help-up-by-two-ends/

This is very common with Rigid Body physics and chains. There's one tutorial here which explains the problem and another here which is more complex but sorts the problem completely (plus all the links that Duarte has just posted)! :^)

Thanks! The tutorials where very useful!
